# How to extend syndication of my site

Tags: seo, marketing, syndication

Currently I am using feedburner, technorati, webmaster tools from google, and updating my RSS to twitter & facebook (via twitterfeed). However, I would like to lay out all of the syndication tools that are generally made use of. As googling this is more than a garbled mess of garbage links, it seems a vetted list would be in order here.

What other syndication tools are out there that provide a 'set it and forget it' value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you site is a blog you can ping lots of aggregators. Here's a list currently recommended by [Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Update_Services):

- http://rpc.pingomatic.com
- http://api.feedster.com/ping
- http://api.moreover.com/RPC2
- http://api.moreover.com/ping
- http://api.my.yahoo.com/RPC2
- http://api.my.yahoo.com/rss/ping
- http://www.blogdigger.com/RPC2
- http://www.blogshares.com/rpc.php
- http://www.blogsnow.com/ping
- http://www.blogstreet.com/xrbin/xmlrpc.cgi
- http://bulkfeeds.net/rpc
- http://www.newsisfree.com/xmlrpctest.php
- http://ping.blo.gs/
- http://ping.feedburner.com
- http://ping.syndic8.com/xmlrpc.php
- http://ping.weblogalot.com/rpc.php
- http://rpc.blogrolling.com/pinger/
- http://rpc.technorati.com/rpc/ping
- http://rpc.weblogs.com/RPC2
- http://www.feedsubmitter.com
- http://blo.gs/ping.php
- http://www.pingerati.net
- http://www.pingmyblog.com
- http://geourl.org/ping
- http://ipings.com
- http://www.weblogalot.com/ping

That page also list other ping services that you may find useful.

Comment: Thanks for that great list. I'm not using Wordpress so I would not have found it otherwise I guess, although some of these sites are referred on Google searches.

Comment: That's why this site is here. So we can share our knowledge. :) That list seems to be actively maintained so it's a good place to check even if you don't plan on using Wordpress.

Answer (score 4):

You can also take a look at these lists of RSS directories:

- [55 RSS Directories](http://www.masternewmedia.org/rss/top55/)
- [RSS and Blog Directories](http://www.toprankblog.com/rss-blog-directories/)
- [RSS Directories](http://npxp.com/rss-directories-list)
- [500 Places to Syndicate Your Content](http://www.buzzblogger.com/500-places-to-syndicate-your-content/)